# Terminology about debug the web app

Tags: javascript, html, css

Usually, when we debug web app, we just hover over our mouse in a element, then we right click it and choose "Inspect". What is terminology of this? What is keywords I can use for searching about this technology? I want to read more tutorial to master this debug method since I since it is very very helpful and useful.

Update: Actually I just want to know a element's css class, so then I can display or hide this element.

Comment: You mean the Developer Tools? Inspecting a source isn't technically debugging... stepping through code line by line to see the execution as it continues, then finding the source of your bugs (and fixing them) is debugging.

Comment: Actually I just want to know a element's css class, so then I can display or hide this element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Developer Console is the most important tool in web development and
>   without it, any web developer can hardly imagine about web page
>   development. It is more important than any IDE we use for development.

1. Inspecting an element on the browser called Client debugging or UI debugging. This happens on Developer console which comes by default with every browser. You can inspect an element on by mouse right click > Select inspect OR Press F12.
2. This will open a console at the bottom of the same browser window like below
   [image]
3. In above image, you can see the element selected is BODY and the CSS aligned with the tag property is visible in the same console under style tab at right-hand side. When you will hover on any CSS property, a checkbox will appear and it will allow you to remove or add the property to selected element.
4. On the same side, there are multiple options which you can apply on css. Eg. If you want to apply some property on **hover**, click on the filter and select the state of the element.
5. This way, you can play with elements on the page and then finalize the element style you are looking for.
6. Developer console is used not only for CSS and HTML, it also used to debug Javascript. It gives you all the controls needed to debug JavaScript at runtime.

[NOTE: Making changes on developer console does not get saved in the actual file. You must need to copy them to source file and then refresh the page to see them working]

Hope this helps, Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you send me more tutorials about "Inspecting an element on the browser called Client debugging or UI debugging". Since I know what you mentioned here, I want to learn more advanced skill about this.

Answer (score 1):

When you "inspect element" you're using the browser's developer tools, or "dev tools." If you're looking for tutorials, googling "chrome developer tools" or "firefox developer tools" (or whatever browser you use) should give you a ton of stuff.

Comment: This one is also very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that  you want to know about client side debugging. which is broadly of 2 types

1. browser level debugging :  you can use [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging)  link to understand for google chrome.
2. Javascript Debugging : you can use [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)  link to know about javascript debugging :